# is there a better way to move folders up a directory than mv?

Tags: linux, bash, filesystems

I downloaded a rather large filestructure (>100GB) to a subfolder of my root directory, lets call it `/folder`.  The problem is, I accidentally copied it into a subfolder of that folder, rather than just directly into that folder, so now I have `/folder/folder/*` instead of `/folder/*` which is what I want.  Is there a better way to remove the extra level than just:

```
# mv /folder/folder/* /folder
# rmdir /folder/folder
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If source an destination are on the same filesystem, mv will just create another directory entry, it will no copy 100 GB of data. So this is the best way to do it, you don't need to search for another way. But if they are on different filesystems, the data will be copied. Also, you don't need to rmdir - mv will do that automatically.

Comment: It won't remove the directory automatically in this case since the folder itself is not being moved. Clearer example: `mv /folder1/folder2/* /folder1` - now you still have `folder2` left, though it is empty.

Answer (score 4):

The `mv` command doesn't move the data in the files, just the names of the files.  If you are worried about all of the data in every file being moved, this won't do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
# cd /folder/folder
# mv * ../
# rmdir /folder/folder
```

but what is the problem with what you had? Can you clarify what you mean by a better way?

Answer (score 0):

A slightly simpler procedure (fewer overall mv operations)

```
  mv /folder /surplusfolder
  mv /surplusfolder/folder /folder
  rmdir /surplusfolder
```